# png isn't precompiled using capistrano to deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (paanouplb_logo_navbar.png isn't precompiled):
    1: <a class="brand" href="<%= posts_path %>">
    2:   <%= image_tag asset_path('paanouplb_logo_navbar.png') %>  
    3: </a>
  app/views/shared/navbar/_brand.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_shared_navbar__brand_html_erb___4534137822881499314_42901420'
  app/views/shared/_navbar.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_shared__navbar_html_erb__3184300490266485791_40918660'
  app/views/layouts/home.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_home_html_erb___1407264114428489351_35989280'
```

In my production.rb I already have

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

I'm deploying through Capistrano.

Comment: Could you give `<%= image_tag('paanouplb_logo_navbar.png') %>` a try?

Comment: do you have 'load deploy/assets' in your Capfile ?